# C# Image RollOver

Tags: c#, image, rollover

greetings, im trying to implement an image rollover on a collection of PictureBox (es) that are place in a tablelayoutpanel and one in each table cell.

here is my code:

```
HomePicBox[picBoxCount].MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.PictureBox_MouseEnter);

HomePicBox[picBoxCount].MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.PictureBox_MouseLeave);
```

==================

```
    private void PictureBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = HomeTableLayoutPanel.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
        PictureBox HomeCurrentPicBox = (PictureBox)(HomeTableLayoutPanel.GetChildAtPoint(p));

        if (HomeCurrentPicBox == null)
            return;

        TableLayoutPanelCellPosition HomeCurrentPosition = HomeTableLayoutPanel.GetCellPosition(HomeCurrentPicBox);

        if (GameModel.HomeCellStatus(HomeCurrentPosition.Column, HomeCurrentPosition.Row) == Cell.cellState.Water)
        {
            HomeCurrentPicBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Scan;
            HomeCurrentPicBox.Refresh();

            gameFormToolTip.SetToolTip(HomeCurrentPicBox, GameModel.alphaCoords(HomeCurrentPosition.Column) + "," + HomeCurrentPosition.Row);

        }
    }

    private void PictureBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = HomeTableLayoutPanel.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
        PictureBox HomeCurrentPicBox = (PictureBox)(HomeTableLayoutPanel.GetChildAtPoint(p));

        if (HomeCurrentPicBox == null)
            return;

        TableLayoutPanelCellPosition HomeCurrentPosition = HomeTableLayoutPanel.GetCellPosition(HomeCurrentPicBox);

        if (GameModel.HomeCellStatus(HomeCurrentPosition.Column, HomeCurrentPosition.Row) == Cell.cellState.Water)
        {
            HomeCurrentPicBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Water;
            HomeCurrentPicBox.Refresh();

            gameFormToolTip.SetToolTip(HomeCurrentPicBox, GameModel.alphaCoords(HomeCurrentPosition.Column) + "," + HomeCurrentPosition.Row);
        }
    }
```

but the rollover is not working! any ideas as to how to implement this correctly?

thanks in advance.

the following:

```
    private void PictureBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox HomeCurrentPicBox = ((PictureBox)(sender));
        HomeCurrentPicBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Scan;

        TableLayoutPanelCellPosition HomeCurrentPosition = HomeTableLayoutPanel.GetCellPosition(HomeCurrentPicBox);
        gameFormToolTip.SetToolTip(HomeTableLayoutPanel, GameModel.alphaCoords(HomeCurrentPosition.Column) + "," + HomeCurrentPosition.Row);
    }

    private void PictureBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox HomeCurrentPicBox = ((PictureBox)(sender));
        HomeCurrentPicBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Water;

        TableLayoutPanelCellPosition HomeCurrentPosition = HomeTableLayoutPanel.GetCellPosition(HomeCurrentPicBox);

        gameFormToolTip.SetToolTip(HomeTableLayoutPanel, GameModel.alphaCoords(HomeCurrentPosition.Column) + "," + HomeCurrentPosition.Row);
    }
```

it does the image rollover right but does not display the tooltip. if i state HomeCurrentPicBox instead of HomeTableLayoutPanel on the tooltip it diplays wrongly.

okay no it works i think. i had to change the AutomaticDelay value of the tooltip.

thanks everyone.

Comment: Have you stepped in the code in the debugger ? Does it go to the line setting the new image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Following should work:

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((PictureBox)sender).ImageLocation = "Resources/logo.png";
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((PictureBox)sender).ImageLocation = "Resources/logoonly.png";
    }
```

Edit: Note that I am using ImageLocation to change the pictures, you can use anything you like, you can use the 'Image' property instead of the ImageLocation and assign an image to it if you wish.

Comment: this is good. it will take some time to implement it but i was looking for something that would use the "sender". thanks.

Comment: the code you provided works for the rollover. but when i try to set tooltip on that control.. well the tip does not show. any ideas? thank you.

Comment: I haven't coded tooltips yet so i can't help you on that one, its working as well so i won't research it :) glad i could help